# .htaccess how to hide php extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Let's suppose I have `.htaccess` file at the wwwroot of my Apache website, say, `www.example.com`.

I want to achieve this effect:

> When the user input the link `www.example.com/dashboard` in the
>   browser, it will actually show content in
>   `www.example.com/dashboard.php`
>
> And if the user directly input the link
>   `www.example.com/dashboard.php` in the browser, it will show error.

---

I've tried the following `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteEngine on

# this is to deny direct access of php files in browser
# that is, when the user input directly 'www.example.com/dashboard.php'
  it will turn to error
RewriteRule \.php$ - [F,L]


# if the link the user input to the browser does not end with .php,
  the code will go down ahead

# this rewrite 'www.example.com/dashboard' to 'www.example.com/dashboard.php'
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L,END]
```

However this will make `www.example.com/dashboard` inaccessible from the browser as well.

If I remove the `RewriteRule \.php$ - [F,L]` line, things are working fine but the user can still input `www.example.com/dashboard.php` in the browser to directly access the php page.

---

I'm still confused how `.htaccess` files are actually processed by Apache.

Is that a flow that executes the code from the beginning to the end line by line? Or something else?

---

**UPDATE**

And this gives me **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**：

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/?(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$ /$1.php [END]
```

I'm quite confused can anyone help explain why this gives too many redirects

Comment: Why would you want to deny requests that still carry the `.php` file name ending? You do not want to frustrate your users, do you? Redirect it instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed the apache http server processes configuration files from top to bottom. That also holds true for distributed configuration files (".htaccess"), *if those are enabled* ...

You can simplify your approach:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule \.php$ - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [END]
```

A variant, easier to read:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule \.php$ - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$ /$1.php [END]
```

Note: there is a difference between `REQUEST_FILENAME` and `REQUEST_URI`. The `QSA` flag is not required here as it is the default. And `L` *and* `END` do not really make sense together (keep in mind: `END` is the new `L`...).

Instead of denying requests that still carry the `.php` file name ending you should redirect those:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/?(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$ /$1.php [END]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: `RewriteEngine on RewriteRule ^/?(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301] ...` gives me "too many redirects"

Comment: I fail to see how that should be the case. Could it be that you mixed that last code block I posted with other stuff?